# Join a room after onRoomConnected is already called

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer

I want to use google's real-time multiplayer service in my Android-Game.
Is it possible to create a room via automatch and after onRoomConnected is called, another player can still join the room?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer

> **Gameplay**
>
> Once the required number of participants for a room have been
>   connected, the room is considered to be 'filled' and gameplay can
>   begin. After participants join a room, your game can allow them to
>   leave the room (effectively dropping them out of the game). However,
>   no new players can join a room after it is 'filled' (not even to fill
>   a spot that a participant has vacated).
>
> In certain advanced scenarios, your game might allow connected
>   participants to start gameplay before all pending invitations have
>   been accepted. If your game supports this mode of gameplay, make sure
>   to handle any participants who join the room after gameplay is
>   underway. Take the following example: In a 3-player racing game, your
>   game session might start the race with two players. During the race,
>   if a third player joins the room, your game can let the newly-joined
>   participant observe the current race as a spectator but not play as a
>   racer. After the race is over, your game can allows all three players
>   to participate as racers in the next round.